# How to grab usernames of ssh connections?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, sh

I need a script which cuts every single username with the following command

```
"ps -ef | grep '[s]shd' | grep -v ^root"
```

After that, I want to put each user in the following group with that command

```
"gpasswd -a $user nginx"
```

Operating system: `CentOs 8.2`

Comment: about active connection? What about `last` or `who` or maybe just `w -i`? (or read the man pages, to get information where they get information of logged users, and how they logged). In any case, you are doing a bad thing. Either you add userd to ngix (e.g. automatically when you create new users), or just change ngix group to be `users`. What you are doing is very dangerous, and probably exploitable

Comment: last and who output doesn't catch vscode ssh connections. The problem is i need a way to put active directory user automatically in the local nginx group. The access is only for internal services and not accessible from outside.

Comment: I think you are doing wrongly with permission (maybe you should reframe, with UNIX style of permission view), and note that existing connections will not get group permission (but at next login).But this comment doesn't answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Cutting the username out of the `ps -ef` output is possible but tricky and potentially fragile. You should look at the options to ps to get exactly the information you want without anything extraneous.

e.g. `ps -C sshd -o user=` looks to be close to what you want.

Comment: Note: there is also `pgrep` on some systems to improve filtering